# Two sides textures on plane and import in to the sketchup (.dae)

Tags: texturing, dae

If I created a plane with two texture faces, I can't export it to sketch up (.dae). The underside of the plane is still grey. In Blender, I can see the bottom side with the texture. I have tried different options but still no positive result. Basically I just need to create the plants in Blender and then create the room with plants etc in Sketch up.
Thank you for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add more info about your setup in Blender ?

Comment: Hello, basically I added leave.png as texture and set up transparent background.
Blend mode is set up to alpha blend.
I see same picutre on both sides in Blender but after export/impúort in to the Sketch just like in pictures upper.

Comment: Blender has double sided illumination by default. You may have to enable it in Sketchup settings

Comment: hmm I am looking but I can´t find this option in sketchup, do you know about any tutorial about creating leaves/plant in Blender and importing in to the Sketch up? I am lost for a couple days. Only way is for me is to use "cube" instead plane and put separated textures on both sides. But I would like to use image.png instead with transparent background instead creating complicated shape. Thank you very much